# Set CommandTimeout of NHibernate SaveOrUpdate call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, timeout

I want to set a lower than default CommandTimeout for a specific call to Session.SaveOrUpdate(myentity) in NHibernate. Is that possible and if so how to do it?

In my code I use the UnitOfWork pattern, so a timeout of a specific unit of work / session would also work fine.

Background for this question: I have a web system. In it there is some logging/debugging information that I want to save, but if the actual db inserts take a long time I rather have the insert fail and return quickly (less than 1 sec) than take a long time. However, for most other database operations the default command timeout is fine. Right now the Inserts are almost always super quick. However if the database for some reason is slow (not something that happens everyday) visitors of the site is affected of my slow logging which I would like to avoid. As the info is not critical I had hoped a easy solution would be to just set timeout of the db calls.

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330031/changing-nhibernate-session-save-command-timeout) will help.  Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo)).SetTimeout(120);

Comment: I tried with: Session.CreateCriteria<RequestLog>().SetTimeout(1);
Session.SaveOrUpdate(requestLog); and then a lock in the database to get a timeout, but it did not work, timeout still takes a long (30 sec?) time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure individual timeouts for updates.

On the other hand:

- `Save`/`Update`/`Delete` methods do not necessarily result in a DB call. Calls occur on `Flush` (except insertions of entities with an identity id)
- `insert`/`update` statements do not normally time out. If they do, something else is wrong with your setup
- You can still configure the global `CommandTimeout`. Make it long enough for your needs.

---

Update: after reading your comment, saying you want to do the *opposite* of what I thought (i.e. setting an extremely low timeout), it became clear that you have an architecture problem.

If the information you are writing is not relevant to the current request, instead of trying to save it "as fast as possible" and just failing if it's not fast enough, you should use a queue (choose any) to do that insert outside the request, or even out of the process / machine.

Comment: I expanded the question with background info. I would be just as happy to have a timeout of a whole UnitOfWork block instead of the specific Save method.

Comment: @viblo let me get this straight... you want to **generate more failures by setting the timeout to one second**???

Comment: Yes. :) I should point out that a low command timeout would be a last defense. Ideally the timeout would never be reached, but it can happen (i.e. it has happened) that the table/s are slow to write to for some reason. A timeout would be a very cheap and easy solution to implement (given that its possible in nhibernate) for something that happen very rarely. A queuing solution would add a lot of extra complexity for a rare special case.